# PHP Iterate Through li List & For Each Item Put Value in Array

Tags: php, html, arrays

I have the following code which I'm using to parse HTML Code and only leave UL and LI tags:

```
function strip_tags_content($text, $tags = '', $invert = FALSE) 
{ 

    preg_match_all('/<(.+?)[\s]*\/?[\s]*>/si', trim($tags), $tags); 
    $tags = array_unique($tags[1]); 

    if(is_array($tags) AND count($tags) > 0) 
    { 
        if($invert == FALSE) 
        { 
            return preg_replace('@<(?!(?:'. implode('|', $tags) .')\b)(\w+)\b.*?>.*?</\1>@si', '', $text); 
        } 
        else 
        { 
            return preg_replace('@<('. implode('|', $tags) .')\b.*?>.*?</\1>@si', '', $text); 
        } 
    } 
    elseif($invert == FALSE) 
    { 
        return preg_replace('@<(\w+)\b.*?>.*?</\1>@si', '', $text); 
    } 
    return $text; 
}

echo strip_tags_content($html, "<ul><li>");
```

This works perfectly fine and I get the following return:

```
<ul><li class="myLi">Item 1</li><li class="myLi">Item 2</li><li class="myLi">Item 3</li></ul>
```

What I want to do next is to assign a variable:

```
$myList = strip_tags_content($html, "<ul><li>");
```

And then for each li value, push the content within that li tag in an array, so I finish with an array containing 3 items: Item 1, Item 2 and Item 3.

But have no idea how to finish this last part. Can someone help please?

Comment: [Don't use regex to parse HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags).

Answer (score 0):

I would do a `str_replace()` on it:

```
$myList = str_replace(array('<li class="myLi">','<ul>','</ul>'), "",  $StringYouHaveAlready);
```

You will be left with just your Items and `</li>` in your string.

Then, you can explode on the `</li>`:

```
$myListArray = explode($myList, "</li>");
```

You should then be left with your array, as you have asked.